# How to send parameters to the Kernel Schedule function in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I am doing a cron in laravel with Schedule, but the date of the parameters for the execution of the cron are not fixed. I have a table that stores the data with which I will later use it as the parameters for cron execution. The problem is that I do not know how, from the controller at the time of writing to a record, I can send that record to the query I have in the kernel for cron.

Here is the function that is in the kernel:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
$schedule->command('inspire')
         ->hourly();

$schedule->call(function() {

    $programacion =
    DB::table('plantrabajoalerta')
    ->select(DB::raw('tareaFechaInicioPlanTrabajoAlerta, tareaHoraPlanTrabajoAlerta, tareaIntervaloPlanTrabajoAlerta, tareaDiaLaboralPlanTrabajoAlerta, tareaDiasPlanTrabajoAlerta, tareaMesesPlanTrabajoAlerta'))
    ->where('idPlanTrabajoAlerta',"=", $id)
    ->get();

    $schedule->command('log:plantrabajo')->cron('minuto hora dia * * *');

});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send anything via call to your cron job. But you can run that code inside your `log:plantrabajo` console command, right?

So you just have to

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();

    $schedule->command('log:plantrabajo')->hourly();
}
```

And on your console command execute that query:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class PlanTrabajoCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'log:plantrabajo';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Do whatever';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $programacion =
            DB::table('plantrabajoalerta')
              ->select(DB::raw('tareaFechaInicioPlanTrabajoAlerta, tareaHoraPlanTrabajoAlerta, tareaIntervaloPlanTrabajoAlerta, tareaDiaLaboralPlanTrabajoAlerta, tareaDiasPlanTrabajoAlerta, tareaMesesPlanTrabajoAlerta'))
              ->where('idPlanTrabajoAlerta',"=", $id)
              ->get();

        foreach($programacion as $evento) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```